# Does azure immersive reader have an sdk for Angular?

Tags: angular, azure-cognitive-services, immersive-reader

Is it possible to implement azure immersive reader in an angular application. I saw one JavaScript SDK [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/immersive-reader-sdk), but it has samples for JavaScript and React JS only. If the implementation is possible please provide a link to the documentation or examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently [Javascript SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/immersive-reader/reference) JavaScript library that allows you to integrate the Immersive Reader into application. You can raise [uservoice request](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/932041-azure-cognitive-services) to have an sdk for angular.  Full details are at the Tech Community blog here: https://aka.ms/ImmersiveReaderAugust2020.

Please follow the Immersive Reader Cognitive Services landing page: https://aka.ms/ImmersiveReaderCS